# rdd.first() does not give an error but rdd.collect() does

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am working in pyspark and have the following code, where I am processing tweet and making an RDD with the user_id and text. Below is the code

```
"""
# Construct an RDD of (user_id, text) here.
"""

import json

def safe_parse(raw_json):
    try:
        json_object = json.loads(raw_json)    
        if 'created_at' in json_object:
            return json_object
        else:
            return;
    except ValueError as error:
        return;


def get_usr_txt (line):

    tmp = safe_parse (line)

    return ((tmp.get('user').get('id_str'),tmp.get('text')));

usr_txt = text_file.map(lambda line: get_usr_txt(line))
print (usr_txt.take(5))
```

and the output looks okay (as shown below)

```
[('470520068', "I'm voting 4 #BernieSanders bc he doesn't ride a CAPITALIST PIG adorned w/ #GoldmanSachs $. SYSTEM RIGGED CLASS WAR "), ('2176120173', "RT @TrumpNewMedia: .@realDonaldTrump #America get out &amp; #VoteTrump if you don't #VoteTrump NOTHING will change it's that simple!\n#Trump htt…"), ('145087572', 'RT @Libertea2012: RT TODAY: #Colorado’s leading progressive voices to endorse @BernieSanders! #Denver 11AM - 1PM in MST CO State Capitol…'), ('23047147', '[VID] Liberal Tears Pour After Bernie Supporter Had To Deal With Trump Fans '), ('526506000', 'RT @justinamash: .@tedcruz is the only remaining candidate I trust to take on what he correctly calls the Washington Cartel. ')]
```

However, as soon as I do

```
print (usr_txt.count())
```

I get an error like below

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-60-9dacaf2d41b5> in <module>()    
  8 usr_txt = text_file.map(lambda line: get_usr_txt(line))
  9 #print (usr_txt.take(5))
---> 10 print (usr_txt.count())    
 11 

/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py in count(self)
   1054         3
   1055         """
-> 1056         return self.mapPartitions(lambda i: [sum(1 for _ in     i)]).sum()
   1057 
   1058     def stats(self):
```

What am I missing? Is the RDD not created properly? or there is something else? how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have returned `None` from `safe_parse` method when there is no created_at element in the parsed json line or when there is an error in parsing. This created error while getting elements from the parsed jsons in `(tmp.get('user').get('id_str'),tmp.get('text'))`. That caused the error to occur

The solution is to check  for `None` in `get_usr_txt` method

```
def get_usr_txt (line):
    tmp = safe_parse(line)
    if(tmp != None):
        return ((tmp.get('user').get('id_str'),tmp.get('text')));
```

Now the question is why `print (usr_txt.take(5))` showed the result and `print (usr_txt.count())` caused the error

Thats because `usr_txt.take(5)` considered only the first five rdds and not the rest and didn't have to deal with None datatype.